# Condition to write in File installation properties of installer project in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

I need to mention conditions to create our project folder under "Extensions" folder of Visual studio if that version of Visual studio is installed on that machine.

The below is the screen-shot of the condition property. But this `[VS13PATH] <> ""` condition is passing even if that version of VS is not installed on that machine.

[image]

Currently `[VS13PATH]` is a property value from 'Registry search' of 'Launch condition' as shown below.

[image]

Can anyone suggest where it is going wrong or suggest me the correct "Condition"?

Answer (score 0):

I removed `\Extensions` from the `DefaultLocation` value and the new vaule is `[VS13PATH]`. I instead created a folder `Extensions` in the file structure of the installer project and the error is fixed.